# How does using the SETF function to extend SETF work?

Tags: lisp, common-lisp, setf

In *Practical Common Lisp* chapter [*17. Object Reorientation: Classes*](http://www.gigamonkeys.com/book/object-reorientation-classes.html) section *Accessor Functions*, I was finding it difficult understanding the way `SETF` is being extended.

The functions:

```
(defun (setf customer-name) (name account)
  (setf (slot-value account 'customer-name) name))
```

`bank-account` class definition:

```
(defclass bank-account ()
  ((customer-name
    :initarg :customer-name
    :initform (error "Must supply a customer name."))
   (balance
    :initarg :balance
    :initform 0)
   (account-number
    :initform (incf *account-numbers*))
   account-type))
```

What I don't understand:

- in the expression `(setf (customer-name my-account) "Sally Sue")` does `(customer-name my-account)` return a SETFable slot-value `customer-name` of the the class `bank-account` which then `SETF` uses to set the value to "Sally Sue"?
- is `(setf (customer-name my-account) "Sally Sue")` actually calling the function above?
- as defined above is `setf customer-name` a function?
- in the function above is `customer-name` in `(setf customer-name)` and `'customer-name` in the body referring to the same thing?
- the section states

  > second element is a symbol, typically the name of a function used to access the place the SETF function will set

  if that's the case then why use the `slot-value` function inside the function's definition when the function can be used to access the place?

Answer (score 12):

In many cases accessing and setting data, one needs two things:

- a way to retrieve something from a data-structure
- a way to set something in a data-structure

Thus one would define a setter function and a getter function. For simple cases they also may look simple. But for complex cases they may not. Now if you know the name of the getter, what is the name of the setter? Or: if you know the name of the setter, what is the name of the getter?

Common Lisp has the idea that you only need to know the name of the getter.

- the getter is called, say, `GET-FOO`
- then the setter function is called `(SETF GET-FOO)`. Always.
- the setter function can be invoked this way: `(setf (get-foo some-bar) new-foo)`. Always.

So you write the `GET-FOO` function. You also write the `(SETF GET-FOO)` function and Common Lisp registers it as a setter function.

`(SETF GET-FOO)` is a list. It's also the name of a function. Here we have the exception: Common Lisp sometimes allows a list as a function name. Thus not all function names are symbols, some are actually lists.

`(setf (customer-name my-account) "Sally Sue")` is actually a call the the defined setter. `my-account` is a variable whose value will be bound to the `account` variable of the setter. `"Sally Sue"` is a string and it will be bound to the `name` variable of the setter.

As a developer you only have to know the getter:

- use of the getter:  `(customer-name my-account)`
- use of the setter: `(setf (customer-name my-account) "Sally Sue")`. `SETF` is a macro, which expands into a call of the setter function.

```
(defun (setf customer-name) (name account)
  (setf (slot-value account 'customer-name) name))
```

Above defines a setter function called `(setf customer-name)`.

```
CL-USER 80 > (function (setf customer-name))
#<interpreted function (SETF CUSTOMER-NAME) 40A00213FC>
```

When the function gets called via the `SETF` macro, it calls another setter - this time using the access to a slot value via the slot name.

Comment: So `(setf (customer-name my-account) "Sally Sue")` calls `(setf-customer-name)`? But that function expects two arguments and only one, `"Sally Sue"`, is passed.

Comment: @BleedingFingers, `(setf customer-name)` is your setter function. Its name not just symbol but a list, so it's not obvious, but when you type `(setf (customer-name my-account) "Sally Sue")`, you invoke your setter and pass two arguments: string "Sally Sue" and object of `bank-account` class.

Comment: Where's this specific behavior defined? Had the `account` been the first argument to `(setf customer-name)` and `name` second would it work the same? (Looks some sort of black magic.)

Comment: The semantics of `setf` functions are defined in the [HyperSpec](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/lw50/CLHS/Body/05_abi.htm). The new value is always passed as the first argument to the `setf` function.

Answer (score 2):

`setf` is a very complex macro that knows how to decode its first argument, which usually looks like a function call, as a "place" and then invokes whatever forms are necessary to set the place to the new value. It's not useful to think of `(customer-name my-account)` as returning anything in the `setf` expression. The `setf` macro applies rules defined in the [HyperSpec](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/lw50/CLHS/Body/05_ab.htm) to its place form and, as a default case, will transform

```
(setf (foo arg0 arg1 ...) new-val)
```

to

```
(funcall #'(setf foo) new-val arg0 arg1 ...)
```

The passage in *Practical Common Lisp* is explaining, in a somewhat elliptic way, what happens behind the scenes when you specify an `:accessor` option in a `defclass` slot definition.