# Lisp what GET function returns?

Tags: lisp

Acording to [Accesor GET](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_get.htm), *get finds a property on the property list[2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24090571/how-does-using-the-setf-function-to-extend-setf-work?rq=1) of symbol whose property indicator is identical to indicator, and returns its corresponding property value*. If the property doesn't exists, it returns NIL.

Then, if

```
(get 'clyde 'species) => nil
```

the expression

```
(setf (get 'clyde 'species) 'elephant)
```

must be the same as

```
(setf nil 'elephant)
```

and fail, but it's not the case.

How it comes that the same `get` produces a *value* in one case and a *place* in the other?

**Edit**

I found the answer here: [How does using the SETF function to extend SETF work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24090571/how-does-using-the-setf-function-to-extend-setf-work?rq=1)

Comment: Your logic doesn't follow. Suppose you have a variable `x` and it currently holds `nil`. Do you conclude that `(setf x 42)` doesn't make sense because it's setting `nil` to 42?  No, you're setting the `x` variable to a new value 42. A place expression only denotes the contents when it is used to access the value; when a place expression is the target of store, then it doesn't simply denote the contents. It also denotes a location where the new contents will go.

Answer (score 2):

Please take a look at [Places and Generalized References](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/05_aa.htm).

Basically, [`setf`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/m_setf_.htm) is a [*macro*](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/03_ababb.htm), so

```
(setf (get 'clyde 'species) 'elephant)
```

is not evaluated sequentially as you seem to think it is, but instead *expanded* to whatever

```
(macroexpand '(setf (get 'clyde 'species) 'elephant))
```

returns in your implementation, and then the *result* is evaluated.

The bottom line is: when `(setf (get 'clyde 'species) 'elephant)` is being evaluated, `(get 'clyde 'species)` is *not* getting evaluated ***at all***.

Comment: I'm aware of `setf` being a macro and expanded, but why the same expression produce two different results?.

Comment: when `(setf (get 'clyde 'species) 'elephant)` is being evaluated, `(get 'clyde 'species)` is not getting evaluated at all.

Answer (score 0):

`setf` is a macro: the job of a macro is to transform code to other code.  So `(setf (get ...) ...)` does not ever call `get`: rather `setf`'s macro function looks at the code it is given and turns it into other code, which is (after any other macros get to do their work) called. Here is what `(setf (get 'foo 'x) 3)` expands into in two implementations:

```
(setf (get 'foo 'x) 3)
 -> (system::%put 'foo 'x 3)
```

```
(setf (get 'foo 'x) 3)
 -> (ccl::set-get 'foo 'x 3)
```

As you can see, `get` is not being called, and there is no reason why it would be in this case.

Comment: Why not `(setf 'foo 'x 3)` instead?

Comment: @CandidMoe: apart from any other reason the syntax of `setf` is `(setf <place> <value> [<place> <value> ...])`: it takes an even number of arguments (in fact `(setf)` is legal as well: the even number of arguments can be zero).